# relationships between nodes scattered in multiple databases

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j Desktop 1.5.7

I have two separate databases(in separate dbms, project):

- Suppliers

Some nodes:

```
create(n: Bolts: {name: 'Holding Corp.', type 'public'})
create(n: Pistons: {name: 'Flemings Company.', type 'private'})
```

- Factories

some nodes:

```
create(n: Boilers: {name: 'xyz'})
create(n: CoolingSystems: {name: 'abc'})
create(n: Piping: {name: 'efg'})
```

Expected relationships:

```
MATCH
  (supplier:Supplier),
  (factory:Factory)
WHERE supplier.name = 'Holding Corp.' AND factory.name = "abc"
CREATE (supplier)-[fixationUnits:SUPPLIES_FIXATION {name: 'SUPPLIES_FIXATION', description: 'sample.'}]->(factory)
RETURN type(fixationUnits), participatedIn.name
```

I couldn't figure out anything from the standard command docs.

Now, based on Google search results, and a peek in blogs about [neo4j Fabric](https://neo4j.com/blog/getting-started-with-neo4j-fabric/), it seems I am expecting a feature that is either unsupported by Neo4j or perhaps is limited to the enterprise edition.

Is Fabric or similar enterprise feature the only way to achieve what I wish to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/fabric/configuration/?ref=blog) is only supported in neo4j Enterprise Edition. In neo4j 5.x, Fabric was replaced with [composite databases](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/5/composite-databases/), which are also only supported in EE.

Comment: but is Fabric the only way to achieve what I wish to do?

Comment: With community edition, a query can only target a single DB.